# Rewrite domain to specific URI

Tags: php, nginx, rewrite

Each domain has own `.conf` file in NGINX.

Now, I have one root project in `/var/www/html/myproject/public` and I want to rewrite the given domains that fall under specific URI, so

having `server_name mywebsite1.com` I want this domain to start not from root but from `/mywebsite1`

having `server_name mywebsite2.com` I want this domain to start not from root but from `/mywebsite2`

**More specifically:**

Entering `http://mywebsite1.com`, browser url remain the same but it rewrites to `/mywebsite1`

Entering `http://mywebsite1.com/about`, browser url remain the same but it rewrites to `/mywebsite1/about`

Entering `http://mywebsite2.com/something`, browser url remain the same but it rewrites to `/mywebsite2/something`

So basically I have one codebase and sub websites under specific URI

How can I do it?

Comment: If they are different domains it doesn't look like this would actually make sense? Do you expect `mywebsite1.com/mywebsite1` to be redirected to `mywebsite1.com/mywebsite1/mywebsite1`?

Comment: @RichardSmith actually no /public/mywebsite isn't a folder, /public has index.php and mywebsite1 is a route inside the controller

Comment: Do you know how `index.php` determines the route? Does it use the `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` value or a query parameter?

Comment: It's a Symfony project, they have own Routing. I just try to do that on NGINX level. 
as said, base code has multiple sub projects that are routed through index.php

so I want somehow force nginx to strip /mywebsite1/ URI when accessing http://mywebsite1.com domain and otherwise it will be http://mywebsite1.com/mywebsite1 as Seth pointed out